# How to write a RegEx to format a CC number

Tags: regex

I've almost got this function working as desired. I'm passing a string that will have certain characters replaced(12 numbers in this first case) with dashes to help hide the CC number, while keeping the last four #'s of the string. I could use some help in replacing a string that's already got certain characters in it.

This function works well if I pass in a string like '9876 5432 1098 1005', but I also need to test a string if it already has characters to hide the CC numbers, like this '************2006'. If I can solve for these two cases, that would be amazing. Thanks in advance for the help :)

```
export const formatCard = (acct: string, hide = false): string => {
  const regExFormula = /\b(?:\d{4}[ -]?){3}(?=\d{4}\b)/gm;
  const subst = `---- ---- ---- `;

  if (hide === true) {
    return acct.replace(regExFormula, subst);
  }
  return acct;
};
```

Comment: Did you try `return acct.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, '-');`?

Comment: thank you very much for the quick reply, Wiktor! your code works very well, but I'm wondering if there's an extra step you could help with that would return a string like this '---- ---- ---- 6789", if I input a string like this "************6789"? thanks again!

Comment: Let me precise: you want to find the last 4 digits and concat ``---- ---- ---- `` with these 4 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
const formatCard = (acct, hide = false) => {
  const regExFormula = /(?:\b(?:\d{4}[ -]?){3}|\*+)(?=\d{4}\b)/g;
  const subst = `---- ---- ---- `;

  if (hide === true) {
    return acct.replace(regExFormula, subst);
  }
  return acct;
};

console.log(formatCard("************6789", true));
console.log(formatCard("1234 5678 1234 5678", true));
```

Now, the `(?:\b(?:\d{4}[ -]?){3}|\*+)` part either matches a word boundary and then three occurrences of four digits followed with an optional space or hyphen, or one or more asterisks.

If you want a purely regex solution you can capture last four digits and then replace with the hyphen mask + placeholders to the group values:

```js
const formatCard = (acct, hide = false) => {
  if (hide === true) {
    return acct.replace(/.*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d).*/, '---- ---- ---- $1$2$3$4');
  }
  return acct;
}

console.log(formatCard("************6789", true));
console.log(formatCard("4124-5460-6-9-5----4", true));
console.log(formatCard("1234 5678 1234 5678", true));
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MwbSMX/1).

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor! I apologize if I wasn't totally clear. There are essentially two things I need to do with this function and the first thing is already figured out in the function I've shared above. I just need help with #2.

#1. be able to pass a string that looks like this '1234 5678 1234 5678' and return a string that looks like this '---- ---- ---- 5678'.
#2. I also need to be able to pass a string that looks like this '************5678' and return a string that looks like this '---- ---- ---- 5678'.

Sorry for any miscommunication

Comment: @blakeferm OK, I replaced the first snippet with a variation of your initial code. My second snippet works as expected from the start and is cleaning even messier inputs.